# TimeSpan don't support years so how do I deal with it? Is there could be smarter solution?

Tags: f#

explain:

**from start day till now I've got 7.7 mb size, how long it will be to make it 10 gb size**

```
open System

let dd = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse("12/09/2012")).Days
let oneday = 7.7 / Convert.ToDouble(dd)

let in10gb = Convert.ToInt32( Math.Round (10.0 * 1024.0 / oneday) )
let years = Convert.ToInt32( Math.Round (float in10gb / 365.0) )
let mutable months = Convert.ToInt32( Math.Round (float (in10gb - years * 365) / 30.0) )
let days = 
    let d = in10gb - years * 365 - months * 30
    if d > 0 then d else month = month - 1; (30 - d)

printf "%d years %d months %d days" years months days
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Also `/ 30.0` for months is dirty hack here... I'm not sure how to avoid it in easy way.

Comment: Be careful with things like `DateTime.Parse("12/09/2012")`. They can give different results on different computes, due to culture settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose an alternative method of calculating your time, using seconds and DateTimes:

```
open System

let startDate = DateTime.Parse ("2012-09-12")
let now = DateTime.Now;
let currentRuntime = (now - startDate).TotalSeconds
let timePerGig = currentRuntime / 7.7;
let tenDate = startDate + TimeSpan.FromSeconds (10.0 * timePerGig);
```

With that done, you can do whatever you like to represent the final date relative to the current date.

An overly simplistic example is as follows:

```
printf "%d years %d months %d days" (finalDate.Year - now.Year) (finalDate.Month - now.Month) (finalDate.Day - now.Day)
```

Of course, you would have to account for roll-over for days and months in any final piece of code, but it illustrates how you could pull the date parts back out.